# Pass jQuery grid value to c#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I would like to pass the studentID from the jQuery code to the C# code function when user clicks on the View link, please advise.

```
    $(document).on("ready", function () {
        obj = {
            width: 940,
            height: 555,
            title: "Students List ",
        };
        obj.colModel = [
                          { 
                             dataIndx: 7, editable: false, sortable: false, title: "Password", width: 65, align: "center", resizable: false, dataIndx: "studentID", 
                             render: function (ui) 
                             {
                                 var rowData = ui.rowData, dataIndx = ui.dataIndx;
                                 var val = rowData[dataIndx];

                                 return "<a href='#" + rowData.studentID + "' style='text-decoration: underline;'>View</a>";

                             }, className: "checkboxColumn"
                          },
                          { title: "Student Name", width: 220, getEditCellData: saveCell, dataIndx: "studentName" },
                          { title: "Student ID", width: 120, getEditCellData: saveCell, dataIndx: "studentID" },
                       ];

        obj.dataModel = {
            dataType: "JSON",
            rPP: 20,
            sortDir: "down",
            rPPOptions: [1, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 100, 500, 1000],
            filterIndx: "",
            filterValue: ""
        };

        }); 

</script>
```

**Grid**

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="PageTitlePlaceHolder" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder" runat="server">
    <div id="grid_table" style="margin: auto;"></div>

</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 3):

Suggest changing your anchor tag to this

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-studentId=rowdata.studentID style='text-decoration: underline;' class='viewStudent' >View</a>
```

After that wire up the click event in jquery for the view button

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $(".viewStudent").on("click", function() {
           .. do what you need to do here ..
      });
});
```

Here is a jsfiddle on how to do this

https://jsfiddle.net/8brpuo82/7/

Comment: I may be doing something wrong. I tried the code like this (return "<a href='javascript:void(0);' data-studentId=rowdata.studentID style='text-decoration: bold;' class='viewStudent' >View</a>";). and after this I used the jquery code with the alert but nothing happened. Please advise.

Comment: Sorry, if I am doing something wrong, but please see code below, no luck yet: $(document).ready(function () {
$(".viewStudent").on("click", function () {
alert("Record Selected...");
});
});

Comment: what version of jquery are you using if you do not mind me asking?

Comment: jquery-ui-1.11.4.min.css

Comment: also change the $ sign to jQuery

Comment: also why does your jquery library have a .css extension? It should be a .js extension

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you may be using web forms here - have you tried using a Hidden Field?  Once you bind the anchor tag click event to a jQuery function:

ahh, I see GJohn beat me to it

... then you should be able to reference that ID within the Page response lifecycle, e.g., `int studentID = hfStudentID.Value;`